# Lenovo Ideapad 100S-14IBR - how to reset to factory settings

Tags: passwords, lenovo-laptop, factory-defaults

I am unable to access a Lenovo Ideapad 100S-14IBR because a supervisor password was set and the person who did this cannot remember the password.
I have tried disconnecting the BIOS battery + main battery and leaving the machine off for over 24hours but it still asks for a password.
Can someone give instructions to reset to factory settings?
The goal is to install Ubuntu MATE 20.04

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://support.lenovo.com/in/en/solutions/ht036206) Lenovo article explains that you will have to take the laptop to a service center and get the motherboard replaced.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I have been through all manner of things it seems that shorting 2 pins on an EEPROM will do the trick but I do not have the information to do this. The laptop is quite old so it would probably be better value to buy another!

Comment: Considering that every laptop motherboard is unique, you will have difficulty identifying the correct pins. If you are not absolutely not sure with what you are doing then don't do this as shorting the wrong pins can have disastrous consequences. As long as the laptop is from the previous decade or so Ubuntu should run just fine.